# Singly linked list in c not working when trying to insert node before first element

Tags: c, linked-list

Given below singly linked list implementation in C  is working fine until I use insertBefore() function below. In insertBefore() when i try to insert node before first element strange thing is happening. I tried printing list from inside insertBefore() which printed the list properly. But there seems some thing wrong when I try to return first. Because after returning in main when i try to print the same list its going in infinite loop. Point is that after returning in main when i tried printing value first.next->data its showing same value as that of first.data. This code was working for all other cases like insertAfter() and even inserBefore() when i tried inserting node at any other positions except before first node.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
   int data;
   node *next;
};

void printList(node *);

node * insertFirst(node *first, int x)
{
 node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 ptr->data = x;
 ptr->next = NULL;
 first = ptr;
 return first;
}

node *insertAfter(node *first, int x, int k)
{
  node *p = first;
  node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  ptr->data = x;

  while(p != NULL)
  {

         if(p->data == k)
                    break;
         p = p->next;       
  }

  if(p == NULL)
      printf("Element not found\n");
  else
  {
     ptr->next = p->next;
     p->next = ptr;
  }
  printList(first);
  return first;
}

node *insertBefore(node *first, int x, int k)
{
  node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  ptr->data = x;
  node *p = first, *follow = NULL;
  while(p != NULL)
  {
         if(p->data == k)
                    break;
         follow = p;
         p = p->next;
  }
  if(p == NULL)
      printf("Element not found\n");
  else
  {
     if(p == first)
     {
          ptr->next = first;
          first = ptr;
     }
     else
     {
         ptr->next = p;
         follow->next = ptr;
     }     
  }
  printList(first);
  printf("first->nxt %u", first->next->data);
  return first;

}

void printList(node *first)
{
  node *p = first;
  while(p != NULL)
  {
         printf(" %d",p->data);
         p = p->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

main()
{
  struct node first, *p;

  int i, x, y, t=1;

  while(t)
  {
          printf("1:insertFirst 2:insertAfter 3:insertBefore 4:printList 5:exit\n");
          scanf("%d", &i);
          switch(i)
          {
                   case 1:
                        printf("Enter element to be inserted\n");
                        scanf("%d", &x);
                        first = *insertFirst(&first, x);

                        break;
                   case 2:
                        printf("Enter element to be inserted\n");
                        scanf("%d", &x);
                        printf("Enter element after which to insert node\n");
                        scanf("%d", &y);
                        first = *insertAfter(&first, x, y);
                        break;
                   case 3:
                        printf("Enter element to be inserted\n");
                        scanf("%d", &x);
                        printf("Enter element before which to insert node\n");
                        scanf("%d", &y);
                        first = *insertBefore(&first, x, y);
                        printf("first: %d", first.data);  
                        printf("first.nxt %d", first.next->data);

                        printList(&first);                     
                        break;

                   case 4:
                        printf("Linked list:");
                        printList(&first);
                        break;             
                   case 5:
                        t = 0;
                        break;
          }

  }
  getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest converting `first` (in `main()`) into a pointer (`node*`) and revisiting all places where you do things like:

```
first = *insertBefore(&first, x, y);
```

This should read:

```
first = insertBefore(first, x, y);
```

Otherwise you're leaking memory left right and center, and creating the possibility for infinite loops (where `first.next` points to `first`).

You'll also need to make sure that `first` is initialized correctly, and replace all uses of `first.X` with `first->X`.

**edit**: Consider the following code:

```
node * insertFirst(node *first, int x)
{
 node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 ...
 return ptr;
}

struct node first;
...
first = *insertFirst(&first, x);
```

The result of `insertFirst()` is dereferenced, and the returned structure is **copied into `first`**. Once the assignment finishes executing, the `malloc()`ed pointer has been lost forever.

There are similar memory leaks affecting the other functions.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But can you please elaborate what you mean by "you're leaking memory left right and center" ? And why exactly was first.next pointing to first after returning to main. Because when I tried printing list from the insertBefore() function by passing first, it did print the list correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `insertFirst` should insert the new node before `first`. However, it does not because the new node should have its `next` pointer point to the old first node.

Try this instead:

```
node * insertFirst(node *first, int x)
{
    node *ptr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->data = x;
    ptr->next = first;  /* The old first node is now second first */
    return ptr;  /* Return the new first node */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert before should be as follows. Assuming you maintain `head` as a global and pass `head` node and `data` of the new node as the arguments.

```
NODE * addfront(NODE *head, int data)
{
        NODE * newnode = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        newnode->data = data;
        newnode->next = head;

        head = newnode;
        return head;
}
```

The above code should be used as follows:

```
NODE * head = NULL;
head = addfront(head, 9);
```